# In DB2, perform an update based on insert for large number of rows

Tags: db2, output, insert-update

In DB2, I need to do an insert, then, using results/data from that insert, update a related table. I need to do it on a million plus records and would prefer not to lock the entire database. So, 1) how do I 'couple' the insert and update statements? 2) how can I ensure the integrity of the transaction (without locking the whole she-bang)?

some pseudo-code should help clarify

**STEP 1**

```
 insert into table1 (neededId, id)        select DYNAMICVALUE, id from tableX      where needed value is null
```

**STEP 2**

```
 update table2 set neededId = (GET THE DYNAMIC VALUE JUST INSERTED)     where id = (THE ID JUST INSERTED)
```

**note:** in table1, the ID col is not unique, so i can't just filter on that to find the new DYNAMICVALUE

This should be more clear (FTR, this works, but I don't like it, because I'd have to lock the tables to maintain integrity. Would be great it I could run these statements together, and allow the update to refer to the newAddressNumber value.)

```
/****RUNNING TOP INSERT FIRST****/*

--insert a new address for each order that does not have a address id
insert into addresses
    (customerId, addressNumber, address)    
select 
    cust.Id, 
    --get next available addressNumber
    ifNull((select max(addy2.addressNumber) from addresses addy2 where  addy2.customerId = cust.id),0) + 1 as newAddressNumber,
    cust.address
from customers cust
where exists (
    --find all customers with at least 1 order where addressNumber is null
    select 1 from orders ord
    where 1=1
    and ord.customerId = cust.id
    and ord.addressNumber is null   
    )


/*****RUNNING THIS UPDATE SECOND*****/          
update orders ord1
set addressNumber = (
            select max(addressNumber) from addresses addy3 
            where addy3.customerId = ord1.customerId
            ) 
where 1=1 
    and ord1.addressNumber is null
```

Comment: Do you actually need the rows inserted into table1 beyond the scope of "step 2", or are you putting them there thinking that's what you need to do to accomplish the update?  In what sense do you mean "dynamic"?  It might help if you can give us the actual scenario, or an analogy that closely models it.

Comment: OK. Dealing with a legacy ecommerce system, where there's an address table that's related to an orders table. The orders table has an FK to the address table, but it can be null. When it's null, the address table is not used.

Comment: ... We are updating the system and now every order recorder needs an addressId. So I need to insert a new address record for each order where orders.addressId (fk field) is null, then populate that field with the new addressId. But, to make matters more complicated.... the ID field in the address table is not unique; it's a 'addressNumber' starting at 1 for each different customer (the key is a compound of customerId and 'addressNumber'). Apologies if this is still confusing.

Comment: Added some actual sql above...

Comment: Maintaining something like `addressNumber` - a counter per-customer - is derived information, and should be avoided if possible.  Especially as your current strategies potentially require locking the table to allow safely getting the new value anyways; if you have an index on `customerId`,`addressNumber`, the optimizer may be able to only lock the effected rows.  You're essentially getting the most recent rows - do you have something like an `insertedAt` timestamp?  What about a per-row-unique key (usually an autonumber column)?

Comment: It's a legacy system, so I can't change the table structure. There's no unique key and there's no timestamp -- but even if there was a timestamp, wouldn't using it effectively be the same as get the max(addressNumber)? There's still a chance for bad data if I'm filtering on max(timestamp).
------
Can you share more about how I might be able to lock only the effected rows? That would be good enough; there's some 5 million rows that will be effected by this and I prefer not to lock each entire table while the thing is processing.

Comment: Ah, it's not something you can _guarantee_, it would be a function of the optimizer (and lock-level chosen); in the case of an index, the optimizer may be able to lock the relevant rows/memory page - however too many rows affected causes it to bump it to the next "level", so you may end up with a table lock anyways.  The reason for this is so you don't _insert_ duplicate `addressNumber`s: interleaved threads may get the same result from the `MAX() + 1`...  Since inserting a timestamp doesn't depend on other rows, that doesn't need as high a lock level.  Find a slow time of day to run this.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Clockwork. Middle of the night it is. Errr... Do you want to move this comment to an answer so I can give you credit?? Also, do you know any DB2 folks looking for a contract work? PM me if you do.

Answer (score 0):

The [IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0004231.html) function is a non-deterministic function that returns the most recently assigned value for an identity column, where the assignment occurred as a result of a single INSERT statement using a VALUES clause

Comment: Um, he's not using a `VALUES` clause, so this wouldn't be helpful.  Plus, there's no identity column.  And `addressNumber` repeats for every `customerId`, so it _can't_ be an auto-generated value...